# Android - Cant select Google Play Services in SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I cant select the Google Play Services SDK in the Android SDK Manager.

What can I do? Should I update something else prior?

[image: As you see, there is nothing in the "Extras" directory.]

I've followed the following description: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated **Android SDK Tools** to the latest version first?

From time to time the format of the files that the SDK Manager checks for updates changes. When that happens, new releases are not shown until you update the SDK Tools package.